# Overload resolution between va_list and ellipsis differs based on the literal value. Why?

Tags: c++

I have two overloaded functions where the only difference is the last argument, in one case being a `va_list` and in the other case being an ellipsis.
I noticed the selected overload is different depending if this last argument is an integer literal 0 or 1.

I made a simplified working example as follows, where I am experimenting with various inputs and found out some other weird scenarios:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

void Func(va_list /*arg*/)
{
    std::cout << "void Fun(va_list);" << std::endl;
}

void Func(...)
{
    std::cout << "void Fun(...);" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Func(0);"  << " >> ";
    Func(0);    
    std::cout << "Func(1);"  << " >> ";
    Func(1);
    std::cout << "Func(-1);" << " >> ";
    Func(-1);

    std::cout << "Func('0');"   << " >> ";
    Func('0');    
    std::cout << "Func('\\0');" << " >> ";
    Func('\0');
    
    std::cout << "Func(\"\");"      << " >> ";
    Func("");    
    std::cout << "Func(\"Dummy\");" << " >> ";
    Func("Dummy");
    std::cout << "Func(nullptr);"   << " >> ";
    Func(nullptr);
    
    std::cout << "Func(0*1);"      << " >> ";
    Func(0*1);
    std::cout << "Func(0.0);"      << " >> ";
    Func(0.0);
    
    std::cout <<"int i = 0; Func(i);" << " >> ";
    int i = 0;
    Func(i);
    std::cout <<"i = 1; Func(i);" << " >> ";
    i = 1;
    Func(i);
    
    static const int j = 0, k = 1;
    std::cout << "static const int j = 0; Func(j);" << " >> ";
    Func(j);
    std::cout << "static const int k = 1; Func(k);" << " >> ";
    Func(k);    
}
```

Compiling this code in [cppshell](https://cpp.sh/?source=%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Ccstdarg%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Avoid+Func(va_list+%2F*arg*%2F)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22void+Fun(va_list)%3B%22+%3C%3C+std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avoid+Func(...)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22void+Fun(...)%3B%22+%3C%3C+std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aint+main()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Func(0)%3B%22++%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(0)%3B++++%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Func(1)%3B%22++%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(1)%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Func(-1)%3B%22+%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(-1)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Func(%270%27)%3B%22+++%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(%270%27)%3B++++%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Func(%27%5C%5C0%27)%3B%22+%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(%27%5C0%27)%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Func(%5C%22%5C%22)%3B%22++++++%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(%22%22)%3B++++%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Func(%5C%22Dummy%5C%22)%3B%22+%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(%22Dummy%22)%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Func(nullptr)%3B%22+++%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(nullptr)%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Func(0*1)%3B%22++++++%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(0*1)%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Func(0.0)%3B%22++++++%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(0.0)%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C%22int+i+%3D+0%3B+Func(i)%3B%22+%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++int+i+%3D+0%3B%0D%0A++++Func(i)%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C%22i+%3D+1%3B+Func(i)%3B%22+%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++i+%3D+1%3B%0D%0A++++Func(i)%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++static+const+int+j+%3D+0%2C+k+%3D+1%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22static+const+int+j+%3D+0%3B+Func(j)%3B%22+%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(j)%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22static+const+int+k+%3D+1%3B+Func(k)%3B%22+%3C%3C+%22+%3E%3E+%22%3B%0D%0A++++Func(k)%3B++++%0D%0A%7D) with C++14 gives the following output:

```
Func(0); >> void Func(va_list);
Func(1); >> void Func(...);
Func(-1); >> void Func(...);
Func('0'); >> void Func(...);
Func('\0'); >> void Func(va_list);
Func(""); >> void Func(...);
Func("Dummy"); >> void Func(...);
Func(nullptr); >> void Func(va_list);
Func(0*1); >> void Func(va_list);
Func(0.0); >> void Func(...);
int i = 0; Func(i); >> void Func(...);
i = 1; Func(i); >> void Func(...);
static const int j = 0; Func(j); >> void Func(...);
static const int k = 1; Func(k); >> void Func(...);
```

As you can see, some calls resolve to the `va_list` overload, while most resolve to the ellipsis overload.

I believe this weirdness may come from the fact that `va_list` is often a `char*`. In Visual C++, I find it defined in `vadefs.h` as `typedef char* va_list;`. However I still do not understand how the overload resolution is working on most cases here.

- How does overload resolution work between `va_list` and ellipsis?
- How could i make a call to `Func(0)` resolve to the ellipsis overload?

Comment: Use: `template<typename... T> void Func(T&&... args) { std::cout << "void Func(...);" << std::endl; }` and it will be called for all cases except `va_list`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `...` overload will only be selected if there is no implicit conversion sequence to `va_list`. In other words, the ellipsis always has the lowest possible priority during overload resolution.

Since the definition of `va_list` is unspecified, in general the results you observe will not be portable: `Func(x)` could call either the `va_list` overload or the ellipsis overload depending on the implementation. The one exception is that `Func(x)` will always call the `va_list` overload when `x` itself has type `va_list` (possibly const-qualified).

If, in fact, `va_list` is `char*` on your system, then a null pointer conversion can occur: in other words, 0 can be implicitly converted to the null pointer of type `char*`. No other integer value can be implicitly converted to a pointer value.

As of C++14, even `'\0'` should not be implicitly convertible to a pointer value. The null pointer conversion only applies to an integer literal with value zero. (Although `'\0'` has integer type, it is not an integer literal.) This particular version of Visual Studio is out of date.

As for your question "How could i make a call to Func(0) resolve to the ellipsis overload?", well, you can't change the rules of overload resolution. What you can do is change the ellipsis overload to a template:

```
template <class T>
void Func(T x);
```

This guarantees that the `va_list` overload will only be called when the argument is `va_list` (possibly const-qualified) and in all other cases, the template will be called since it will give an exact match. Yet, a problem still remains: you may have some `char*` variable, which you think of as not being a `va_list`, and calling `Func` with it as an argument could call the `va_list` overload since `va_list` **is** `char*` (on your system). There's no way to prevent this. Maybe you shouldn't be overloading `Func` at all. You can have two separate functions instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Things make more sense now.